# I need to update the post query?

Tags: loop

I am trying to simply update the post query to only query posts with the taxonomy.

Comment: state is CPT or taxanomy?

Comment: WHy you delted all the code and comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use tax_query.

```php
$args = 
  [
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'state',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'minnesota', // lowercase m
        ),
  ];
```

Comment: Excellent! You can mark this answer as best answer.

Comment: I not understood the quetion. You may want to open a new question.